# JW Player 7 Controllbar styling issue - how do I get rid of the border?

Tags: jwplayer, jwplayer7

I am trying to customize the controlbar background. I need to get a transparent background for the controllbar

I am using "seven" theme. This is my setup for the theme.

```
jwplayer("container").setup({                
                    "width": 848,
                    "height": 477,
                    "type": "mp4",
                    "autostart": auto,
                    "provider": "video",                    
                    "file": VIDEO_PATH,
                    "image": THMB_PATH,
                    "skin": { name: "seven", active: "#ff2b2b", inactive: "#fff", background: "rgba(0,0,0,.5)" },
                    "events": { "onReady": function () { vv.setPlayerStatus("Ready"); } },
                    "modes": [
                      { "type": "html5" },
                      { "type": "flash", src: "/content/js/webcam/new/jwplayer.flash.swf" },
                      { "type": "download" }
                    ]                    
                });
```

As you can see I am using background: "rgba(0,0,0,.5)" as background.

**"skin": { name: "seven", active: "#ff2b2b", inactive: "#fff", background: "rgba(0,0,0,.5)" }**

This works but I see a darker border on top and bottom of the horizontal slider
as shown in this image (see red arrows)

[image]

If I make it 100% transparent then the border goes away. But the problem is any video with white BG make the controllbar invisible. So I want 50% transparency.

I tried various options from [JW Player skin reference](https://support.jwplayer.com/customer/en/portal/articles/2067702-skin-css-classes-reference-)  but nothing helped.

Any idea how to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to target the time slider component specifically and make it transparent. This will then allow the 50% transparency applied to the parent control bar to take affect.

Also, because the JW styles are added dynamically, they will appear after your styles - later in the style cascade - and so in order for your declaration to be honoured you'll need to include the "!important" flag:

```
.jw-skin-seven .jw-slider-time{ background:transparent!important;}
```

Comment: I see, it works! There is a one line black border on top of the control bar. Is there a way to customize that color?

Comment: .jw-skin-seven .jw-controlbar {
  border-top: #333 1px solid;
  height: 2.5em;
}

Answer (score 1):

Try:

**CSS**

```
.jw-skin-seven .jw-slider-horizontal,
.jw-skin-seven .jw-slider-container, 
.jw-skin-seven .jw-rail { 
    border: 0 none rgba(0,0,0,.5); 
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5); 
    outline: 0 none rgba(0,0,0,0);
}
```

If that doesn't work use `!important`

```
.jw-skin-seven .jw-slider-horizontal,
.jw-skin-seven .jw-slider-container, 
.jw-skin-seven .jw-rail { 
    border: 0 none rgba(0,0,0,.5) !important; 
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5) !important; 
    outline: 0 none rgba(0,0,0,0) !important;
}
```

If that doesn't work try

```
.jw-skin-seven .jw-slider-horizontal.jw-slider-horizontal,
.jw-skin-seven .jw-slider-container.jw-slider-container, 
.jw-skin-seven .jw-rail.jw-rail { 
    border: 0 none rgba(0,0,0,.5) !important; 
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5) !important; 
    outline: 0 none rgba(0,0,0,0) !important;
}
```

Declaring a class twice actually works, I forgot how I found this out, and it's not documented or I can't find the key terms to invoke the right search.

Comment: It doesn't work. I tried all 3. JW Player documentation doesn't work as per mentioned.

Comment: I think your best bet is to email support since you have a premium license. For what they charge per year, you better get results. I'm slowly phasing out JWPlayer since it's main features center around ads nowadays. Good luck, sir.

Comment: If you are phasing out jw player, what are you going to use? Thanks

Comment: Plain old HTML5 video, but my circumstances differ from most developers'. I don't run ads, no streaming, and my clients are required to use either Chrome, Firefox, or Safari. None of that IE nonsense. But if you stream and/or run ads, JW Player is a must.